# PostGIS ST_Intersects GeometryCollection

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

If i'm not terribly mistaken, `ST_Intersects` does not support GeometryCollection.

```
ERROR:  Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.
HINT:  Change argument 2: 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((.......
```

Currently i am using a [wrapper](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/attachment/ticket/256/ST_Intersects_.sql) that cycles through the different types in a GeometryCollection and performing a `ST_Intersect` on each. Needless to say, this is terribly inneficient.

There must be a better way?

Comment: So it is documented in http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html `Do not call with a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION as an argument for geometry version.`

Comment: @user30184 i was just there reading this. seems the workaround is to switch to geography instead of geometry. or not? i hope im not opening a can of worms.

Comment: You could use ST_Dump with a ST_GeometryType in the where or ST_CollectionExtract to pull out the types you want and then run the Intersects. It will be more efficient if you create a new table and add a spatial index, naturally

Comment: I'm curious, why do you say that the wrapper is "terribly inefficient" ?  What would a more efficient implementation look like?

Comment: @dbaston if im not terribly mistaken, its innefficient because if i search 1000 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION's against a point it will be 2000+ queries under the hood (based on my dataset where each GEOMETRYCOLLECTION has at least 2 different geometries). a more efficient implementation? i really don't know. that's my question :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the PostGIS documentation for the [ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) function, the PostGIS version "2.5.0 Supports GEOMETRYCOLLECTION".

It may be good to note that, the [PostGIS version 2.5.0 release news](https://postgis.net/2018/09/23/postgis-2.5.0/) states that "this release will work for PostgreSQL 9.4 and above but to take full advantage of what PostGIS 2.5 offers, you should be running PostgreSQL 11beta4+ and GEOS 3.7.0".

Comment: ty for the update, putting the accepted mark on this answer

Answer (score 11):

Spatial relation operators do not work on geometry collections by design, as inherited from JTS.

Try using [ST_CollectionHomogenize](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionHomogenize.html), which will return a regular geometry, if possible. Or [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) to specify a geometry type.

Comment: According to the PostGIS documentation, https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html, the PostGIS version "2.5.0 Supports GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" and the version works "for PostgreSQL 9.4 and above", https://postgis.net/2018/09/23/postgis-2.5.0/