# Building efficient multi geometry type database with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, st-intersects, geometrycollection

I'm trying to build a PostGIS database which must be able to store (multi)points, (multi)linestrings and (multi)polygons. The goal is to efficiently querying the data with ST_Intersects and other related functions.

My first look was at GeometryCollection. I thought that was tailor-made for my needs, i thought i'll just dump various geometry types to a GeometryCollection, create an index and forget about it. Well, then i realized that [ST_Intersects does not support GeometryCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/postgis-st-intersects-geometrycollection/).

So my plan B is to store each data type independently in a column (with indexes of course) and query the database using OR clauses for each data type column like:

`WHERE (ST_Intersects(a_geometry, point_geometry) OR ST_Intersects(a_geometry, linestring_geometry) OR ST_Intersects(a_geometry, polygon_geometry))`

With proper indexes set, this looks efficient, but in this day and age i suspect there must be some better way? Some better approach that is common enough but i am not aware of?

All queries on database will be `SELECT`s. Data insertion will be a one time process.

Comment: Define just one geometry column to be of a general GEOMETRY type and you can store all kind of geometries into it. Some clients like QGIS will have troubles because it can't handle points, lines, and polygons in a same layer but if you work inside PostGIS it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the docs.  A geometry collection is something of the form:

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(....).

Just because you have a mix of multipoints, multilinestrings and multipolygons in the same geometry column doesn't make them a geometry collection.  multis are not considered geometry collections either.

If you truly plan to have GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONs in your geometry column,

You can use ST_DWithin with a small tolerance or no tolerance.  ST_DWithin works with geometry collections -

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_DWithin.html

So replace your ST_Intersects with (0 or low tolerance)

ST_DWithin(a_geometry, point_geometry, 0);

Comment: i'll go back to the docs for a re-read but please help me straight this out. my column on database is of type `geometry(GeometryCollection,4326),` and **one** record there contains a **mix** of (multi)points,(multi)linestrings and (multi)polygons. Isn't that a geometry collection? If not what it is? Multipoints is not a geometry collection, but a **mixture** of multipoints **and** multilinestrings is a geometry collection? Am i correct?

Comment: You want your column to be `geometry(geometry, 4326)` . The geometry subtype type is  a catchall for any 2d geometry (including multies and geometry collection).  GeometryCollection only supports things like GEOMETRYCOLLECTION. Yes the record with mix of multipoints etc. would be a geometry collection - but probably looks like GEOMETRYCOLLECT(MULTIPOINT(..), MULTIPOLYGON(..)).

Comment: So you mean "a database which must be able to store (multi)points, (multi)linestrings and (multi)polygons.for **each feature**? In that case the both GeometryCollection and three separate geometries are good in theory.

Comment: You are right that a mixture of different geometries can only be stored as GeometryCollection. However, GeometryCollection doesn not need to be a mixture, this is also valid `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POINT ( -40 20 ))`.

Comment: for the record i went with `geometry(geometry, 4326)` as advised in your comment thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your plan to store each data subtype independently in a column is the right choice. As written in the book "PostGIS in Action", the use of the GeometryCollection subtype is not recommended: "*In real-world applications, you should rarely define a data column as geometry-collection . Although having a collection is perfectly reasonable for storage purposes, using it within a function rarely makes any sense [...] You should be prepared to work with them, but avoid using them in your table design.*" (Obe R. and Hsu L., 2015).